# CAS protocol - refresh token?

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, cas

I went over the `CAS` server documentation over and over and am quite aware of data flow between client, server and app.

However, I am particularly interested in what happens in the following scenario:

- User arrives at application, inputs the credentials and get authorized by `CAS` server
- PHP receives the answer, creates the `PHPSESSID`
- At some point in time, administrator removes that user from registry (be it DBMS, LDAP or whatever)
- User sends request for protected resource - **receives the resource**

So, as you might see, **security** is my main issue here. How and when does the session/access token get verified/refreshed?

This question is about `CAS` and `BeSimpleSsoAuthBundle` but I believe it applies to other similar-purpose protocols.

This is what I have tried:

- Installed/configured `CAS` on separate box
- Installed/configured applicaation on another box
- Used application to authenticate via `CAS` - success
- User tries to access protected resource - success
- Brought down `Tomcat` server that runs `CAS`
- Tried to access protected resource in application - **success** (?!)

If I have missed something I'll be more than happy to update my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the Chairman of CAS and founder of CAS in the cloud (https://www.casinthecloud.com).

It's the general design of CAS: you have clients and a server, which provides some advantages, but one of the main concerns is the fact that after being authenticated in your application, you may not communicate with the CAS server again.

In real life, except if you use remember-me, it's not generally a problem. After a few hours (at worst), the SSO / web sessions end and the removed user can no longer log in.

Comment: Thanks @jleleu. I wasn't aware of such concept. I will, however, use the remember-me option in my application. Nevertheless, since my application(s) will be hosted on a single server, I feel like I could just access the sessions' store and remove the one need (automatically of course). Do you have any other suggestion? :)

Comment: Seems good to me. For a long session (remember-me), you need to implement shorter checks on the user to ensure he still exists

Comment: Thanks a lot @jleleu :) I am laying some research groundwork for a project that will begin in a few weeks so don't be surprised if you see some more questions about `CAS`from me ;)